# Determining if a number is divisible

Tags: ruby

I've already reduced it and have tried making the main code `is_divisible=`, followed directly by the `(2...).each...` code, but that didn't work.

Any suggestions on reducing the size of this code? I have tests for other methods that use the code (so I know if changes are working) but not unit tests for this method yet.

```
  def self.divisible?(n)
    is_divisible= false
    (2...n).each do |divisor|
      division=n/divisor
      if n== divisor*division
        is_divisible= true
      end 
    end 
    is_divisible
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  def self.divisible?(n)
    is_divisible= false
    (2...n).each do |divisor|
      division=n/divisor
      if n== divisor*division
        is_divisible= true
      end 
    end 
    is_divisible
  end
```

since you're returning a flag just after computing it, you could just `return true` instead of setting the flag, and `return false` if you get to the end. This saves you one line. But, Ruby arrays have the `any?` and `all?` predicates. Let's rewrite your code to use `any?`. This reduces the `if` condition to only its head. I hope you don't mind if I normalise the whitespace along the way:

```
def self.divisible?(n)
  (2...n).any? do |divisor|
     division = n / divisor
     n == divisor * division
  end
end
```

we could inline `division` (`n == (n / division) * division`), but let's use the modulo operator instead. Note that unlike your algorithm, modulo even works for floats and even rationals.

```
def self.divisible? (n)
  (2...n).any? do |divisor|
     n % divisor == 0
  end
end
```

If you don't mind, I'll reduce the line count further by performing a style change here.

```
def self.divisible? (n)
  (2...n).any? {|divisor| n % divisor == 0}
end
```

I don't think you can get shorter than that.

but if your intention is to generate a list of primes, you should only test divisibility by said primes.

```
def primes_until n
  list = []
  (2..n).each do |x|
    list << x unless list.any? {|d| x % d == 0}
  end
  list
end
```

Written as a `reduce`:

```
def primes_until n
  (2..n).reduce([]) do |list, x|
     list << x unless list.any? {|d| x % d == 0}
     list
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, I think this is equivalent to you your version.

```
require 'prime'

def self.divisible?(n)
  !n.prime?
end
```

If you don't want a dependency on the standard library then Jan Dvorak has a better solution.